# Send multiple emails based on radio

Tags: forms, joomla

in my Joomla website, I have a form where at the end I would like user choose a radio button to send email to:
- name@nobody.com
- List of many email

At the moment I am using a form by RS FORM pro component for joomla.

And the code generated is:

```html
<div class="rsform-block rsform-block-radio">
 <div class="formControlLabel">{radio:caption}<strong class="formRequired">(*)</strong></div>
  <div class="formControls">
   <div class="formBody">{radio:body}<span class="formValidation">{radio:validation}</span></div>
   <p class="formDescription">{radio:description}</p>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Any idea about how to do it? Maybe via Javascript?

Thanks a lot for your help!

Filippo

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**:
To have the radio determine to send it to one email or a list, set the values of the actual radio to the recipient values.
So if the radio was named **send_to**, then the values would be

```
one@mysite.com|Choice 1
```

```
two@mysite.com,three@mysite.com,four@mysite.com|Choice 2
```

Then in the email setup, you would set the TO for **{send_to:value}**
For a related reference:
https://www.rsjoomla.com/support/documentation/rsform-pro/frequently-asked-questions/how-do-i-setup-multiple-recipients-or-recipients-based-on-selection-.html  
https://www.rsjoomla.com/video-tutorials/rsformpro/episode-7-how-to-send-e-mails-to-recipients-listed-in-a-drop-down-field.html

Comment: Hello and thank you for your kind reply!
I had already see n these turorials but this is not my case.

I want the user had 2 options (this is why I want a radio button):

option 1 = send the form only to one email address
option 2 = send the form only to a determined list of emails

Comment: Thank you so much! It works! All the best to you! ;-)